# SDL window sometimes fails to close on CTRL+C in terminal

Tags: c++, sdl

Pressing CTRL+C while in the terminal sometimes fails to end the program:

```cpp
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
  DrawingWindow window = DrawingWindow(WIDTH, HEIGHT, false);
  SDL_Event event;
  while(true) {
    if (window.pollForInputEvents(event)) handleEvent(event);
      draw();
      window.renderFrame();
    }
  }
}

bool DrawingWindow::pollForInputEvents(SDL_Event &event) {
    if (SDL_PollEvent(&event)) {
        if ((event.type == SDL_QUIT) || ((event.type == SDL_KEYDOWN) && (event.key.keysym.sym == SDLK_ESCAPE))) {
            SDL_DestroyTexture(texture);
            SDL_DestroyRenderer(renderer);
            SDL_DestroyWindow(window);
            SDL_Quit();
            printMessageAndQuit("Exiting", nullptr);
        }
        SDL_Event dummy;
        // Clear the event queue by getting all available events
        // This seems like bad practice (because it will skip some events) however preventing backlog is paramount !
        while (SDL_PollEvent(&dummy));
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}

void printMessageAndQuit(const std::string &message, const char *error) {
    if (error == nullptr) {
        std::cout << message << std::endl;
        exit(0);
    } else {
        std::cout << message << " " << error << std::endl;
        exit(1);
    }
}
```

When CTRL+C succeeds (which is most of the time), it does print `"Exiting"`.

Comment: Your code have a comment describing exactly why it happens. Replace `if(SDL_PollEvent)` with `while(SDL_PollEvent)`, and remove everything after dummy event. Unless you do something very specific discarding events is wrong.

Comment: @keltar Including the `return true`? Or should that remain / be moved? I imagine I need that still in some way

Comment: There are many ways to do it. I haven't noticed you have a separate function that also processes events, and it is unclear if drawming is inside if() condition. Check out my answer for a possible solution.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what `handleEvent` supposed to do, and your code have braces mismatch so looks like it isn't even your actual code. As written, `pollForInputEvents` fetches one event, checks if it could be considered a quit condition, and then discards all other events in the queue regardless. If event you're looking for happens to be non-first (e.g. as first event you may have keydown of 'ctrl' or mouse move, or window close event, ...), then it never gets processed. `handleEvent` has the same problem - it gets only first event in frame.

Generally speaking, event processing have to happen in a fast non-blocking loop, which handles events faster than new events are getting in. Processing only one event per frame is a not fast enough, and there is absolutely no reason to process only one event. Events gets accumulated in a queue, you process **all** events, draw your image frame (potentially slow), present on screen (potentially blocking on vsync), then repeat.

It looks counterintuitive that your event processing is split into two functions.

As I don't see the rest of your code, with "minimal" changes it should be something like:

```
#include <SDL2/SDL.h>
#include <iostream>

#define WIDTH  640
#define HEIGHT 480

static void handleEvent(SDL_Event &event) {}
static void draw(SDL_Renderer *renderer) {
    SDL_SetRenderDrawColor(renderer, 0, 0, 0, 255);
    SDL_RenderClear(renderer);
}

class DrawingWindow {
public:
    DrawingWindow(int width, int height, bool fs) {
        SDL_Init(SDL_INIT_VIDEO);
        window = SDL_CreateWindow("test",
                SDL_WINDOWPOS_UNDEFINED, SDL_WINDOWPOS_UNDEFINED,
                width, height, 0);
        renderer = SDL_CreateRenderer(window, -1, SDL_RENDERER_PRESENTVSYNC);
    }
    bool pollForInputEvents(SDL_Event &event);

    void renderFrame() {
        SDL_RenderPresent(renderer);
    }

    SDL_Window *window;
    SDL_Renderer *renderer;
};

void printMessageAndQuit(const std::string &message, const char *error) {
    if (error == nullptr) {
        std::cout << message << std::endl;
        exit(0);
    } else {
        std::cout << message << " " << error << std::endl;
        exit(1);
    }
}

bool DrawingWindow::pollForInputEvents(SDL_Event &event) {
    if (SDL_PollEvent(&event)) {
        if ((event.type == SDL_QUIT) || ((event.type == SDL_KEYDOWN) && (event.key.keysym.sym == SDLK_ESCAPE))) {
            SDL_DestroyRenderer(renderer);
            SDL_DestroyWindow(window);
            SDL_Quit();
            printMessageAndQuit("Exiting", nullptr);
        }
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    DrawingWindow window = DrawingWindow(WIDTH, HEIGHT, false);
    SDL_Event event;
    while(true) {
        while(window.pollForInputEvents(event)) handleEvent(event);
        draw(window.renderer);
        window.renderFrame();
    }
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately this causes the program to stop responding

Comment: The separation of `handleEvent` is because the `DrawingWindow` implementation was intended to be abstracted. However, I can still modify it if necessary.

So `handleEvent` does things such as allowing me to rotate the scene with the arrow keys.

Comment: Your reasoning is your own, do whatever is better for you. I've added complete example on how it should be, including the parts that were not in your question, so it is fully compilable and verifyable. You can check it as separate program and compare with yours.

Comment: I appreciate that, but as mentioned introducing the while loop within the while loop results in the program crashing

Comment: Have you tested full example in my answer, without any other additions? Processing events in inner loop is pretty much the only sane way to process events. If you have problem with that, then you have a problem in either your code or your environment.

Comment: Yes, the only modifications I made are the ones you suggested. Before, it did not crash and now it says "<ProgramName> is not responding"